# Clear all textboxes in vb.net throws an error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am using the following as a workaround:

```
Public Sub ClearTextBox(ByVal root As Control)
        For Each ctrl As Control In root.Controls
            ClearTextBox(ctrl)

            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text = 0
            If TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then CType(ctrl, ComboBox).Text = String.Empty

        Next ctrl
End Sub
```

the reason i am setting the textboxes to 0 is because when I set String.Empty, one text box (containing only Int16) throws a conversion error.  anyone help on stopping the error or just ignoring that one textbox?

As per Andrews response, I ran the code again, and i get the following:

`+        $exception  {"Conversion from string """" to type 'Short' is not valid."}   System.InvalidCastException`

The code highlighted is:

`Dim age As Int16 = Txt_CharAge.Text`

Please bear with me a little, I am totally new to this and am completely self taught. If you need further code to help, just let me know.
Thanks

Comment: OK, thanks for updating the question. What do you want the value of `age` to be when there is nothing in `Txt_CharAge.Text`?

Comment: It doesn't have to be anything, just an empty string is fine.  the workaround, works for that textbox, but i have others which would normally contain actual text and whilst the 0 works, it looks very odd when you know its looking for text answers and not integers.

Comment: A workaround is `Dim age As Integer = cint("0"+Txt_CharAge.Text.trim())` this will always be a valid number. Note that will not work with +/- sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a line such as

```
Dim age As Int16 = Txt_CharAge.Text
```

you are telling the computer to put a string into a number. Without Option Strict On, it is free to make up any way it likes of stuffing a string (which is not an Int16) into an Int16. You have given up your control of what is happening at that point.

The better way is to tell it how to convert the characters of the text into a number. (See [The Treachery of Images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) for an explanation that a representation of some thing is not that thing.)

There is a ready-made set of methods named `TryParse` for many of the built-in types.

So, instead of

```
Dim age As Int16 = Txt_CharAge.Text
```

you should have

```
Dim age As Integer
Integer.TryParse(Txt_CharAge.Text, age)
```

The `TryParse` methods are actually functions which return `True` if the parse was successful, otherwise they return `False` (and set the variable to its default value), but in this case it appears that you don't need to know if the parse succeeded because the default value of 0 for an Integer will suffice.

Note that there isn't really a need to use an Int16 instead of an Integer unless you know why you need to add the complication of using an Int16 instead of an Integer.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the full explanation as well, that has really helped.

Comment: @Silver616 Thanks, glad you found it useful :)